# Normality of the maximal subgroups of the Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

**Question:** I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a finite (non $p$-group) group such that the maximal subgroup in every Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ is normal in $G$ (for each prime $p$).  Then  either $P$  is abelian, or, $P$ has a unique maximal subgroup.

My attempt as follows:

If $P$ is abelian (non-cyclic) then the theorem holds. So, assume that $P$ is non-abelian and has at least two maximal subgroups say $M_1$  and $M_2$. Suppose that $|P|=p^k$, then $|M_1|=|M_1|=p^{k-1}$. For $M_1$  and $M_2$ we consider two cases:

**1.** $M_1 \cap M_2 \ne 1$. Then we let $M_1 \cap M_2 =N$ which is normal in $G$ as intersection of two normal subgroups. and using induction on $G/N$ we get the result.

**2.** $M_1 \cap M_2 = 1$. Then $P= M_1  M_2$. Moreover,$|P|= |M_1 | |M_2|/|M_1 \cap M_2|$. Which implies, $p^k=p^{2k-2}$. Hence, $k=2$ and $P$ is abelian. Cotradiction.

I was wondering if I missed some thing!
It is helpful to remind that groups with the prescribed property is supersolvable. 
Please advice. 
Thank you!.

Comment: The statement that you are trying to prove is not true in general. Your inductive argument in Step 1 does not work, because $P/N$ abelian does not imply that $P$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out the deficiency in the induction part. But I still cannot see why the proposed statement is false. Let be phrase it in another form:

Comment: Let $G$ be a finite (non $p$-group) group such that the maximal subgroup in every Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ is normal in $G$ (for each prime $p$).  Then  either $P$ has a unique maximal subgroup and $P$ will be cyclic or $P$  is abelian,

Comment: When you write "such that the maximal subgroup in every Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal in $G$", do you mean "such that every maximal subgroup in every Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal in $G$"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant. In please of saying for every Sylow p-subgroup. I used (for each prime $p$).

Comment: In any case the statement is false. $D_8 \times C_3$ is a counterexample with $P=D_8$.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is inspiring, One moor example I guess: $Q_8 \times C_3$.